# Function not saving unchecked checkbox

Tags: functions

I'm trying to save custom option for taxonomies in `wp_options`. The following function saves the post id in array if checkbox is checked but when I uncheck the checkbox it doesn't removes term id from wp_options.

```
function wpfs_save_tax($term_id) {

$featured_tax = get_option('_featured_tax');
if(empty($featured_tax) ) {
    $featured_tax = array();
}

if (isset($_POST['wpfs_tax'])) {

    if(!in_array($term_id, $featured_tax) ) {
    $featured_tax[] = $term_id;
    }

} else {

    if(in_array($term_id, $featured_tax) ) {
        unset($featured_tax[$term_id]);
        }

} //isset

update_option('_featured_tax', $featured_tax);
}
```

Please review my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly by what I see in your code: you are trying to `unset` incorrectly, `unset` works by means of an array key and you are using `$term_id` which is a value. You need to find the index in the array for that `$term_id`:

```
function wpfs_save_tax( $term_id ) {
    $featured_tax = get_option( '_featured_tax' );

    if ( empty( $featured_tax ) ) {
        $featured_tax = array();
    }

    if ( isset( $_POST['wpfs_tax'] ) ) {
        if ( ! in_array( $term_id, $featured_tax ) ) {
            $featured_tax[] = $term_id;
        }
    } else {
        if ( in_array( $term_id, $featured_tax ) ) {
            unset( $featured_tax[array_search( $term_id, $featured_tax )] );
        }
    }

    update_option( '_featured_tax', $featured_tax );
}
```